# Having trouble quitting sched.scheduler module?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, multiprocessing, scheduler

I'm using Selenium Webdriver in my program in order to try and automate something. I am then parsing th resulting page, and checking for a specific element in the page. If the page doesn't have the specific element, then I use sched.scheduler to re-automate the task, by having the user click a button (in the Tkinter GUI). The button runs a function, which schedules a task for sched.scheduler, and has the task be sent to a function in which I created a new process from the multiprocessing module.

This is basically what it is:

```
import time
import sched
from multiprocessing import Process

#the function needs to run for the first time, then waits for user input if an error shows up
#if it's the second time around, the worker function runs the scheduler
global first_time_happening
first_time_happening = True
terminate = False
scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)


def worker():
    #insert some working process here using selenium webdriver
    print("Worker happened!")
    global first_time_happening
    if first_time_happening:
        first_time_happening = False
    elif not first_time_happening:
        global relay_to_timer
        relay_to_timer = scheduler.enter(5, 2, timer)
        scheduler.run()


def process():
    p = Process(target=worker)
    #p.daemon = True
    p.start()


def timer():
    if not terminate:
        global relay_to_process
        relay_to_process = scheduler.enter(5, 2, process)
        scheduler.run()
    if terminate:
        scheduler.cancel(relay_to_process)
        scheduler.cancel(relay_to_timer)


def quit_button():
    global terminate
    terminate = True
    if scheduler.empty:
        print("The line is empty")
    elif not scheduler.empty:
        print("Something in the queue!")
    while not scheduler.empty:
        scheduler.cancel(relay_to_process)
        scheduler.cancel(relay_to_timer)

worker()

#simulating where the GUI asks a question, person presses a button, and the button redirects them
#to function worker()

worker()

#simulating a user press the quit button
quit_button()
```

It keeps running even after I "hit" quit (or call the quit function in this case). I keep getting the queue is empty, but I'm not sure why it isn't working? Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scheduler keeps running even with an empty queue just in case somebody (presumably another thread) entered something again.  I believe the way to make it end is to raise an exception (whether from the action or delay function) -- `.run` will propagate it and you can catch it.

To wit...

```
class AllDoneException(Exception): pass

def worker():
    #insert some working process here using selenium webdriver
    print("Worker happened!")
    global first_time_happening
    if first_time_happening:
        first_time_happening = False
    elif not first_time_happening:
        global relay_to_timer
        relay_to_timer = scheduler.enter(5, 2, timer)
        try:
            scheduler.run()
        except AllDoneException:
            pass
```

and in function `timer`

```
    if terminate:
        raise AllDoneException
```

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what are you doing when you bring class AllDoneException(Exception): pass? Does it represent something or is it an actual class (sorry for the noobish question)?

Comment: It's an actual class, a custom exception that does nothing special except being distinguished from any other exception, so that the `except` clause can be very precise.  Catching exception too broadly is terrible practice: be as narrow as you possibly can!

Comment: Okay so I tried doing this, and the program still keeps running...could the problem be that I raise the exception in one function (timer), and by the time the worker function is being executed, the exception is "lost?" so the scheduler still runs? (Again, sorry, I'm kind of new at this so I might be totally off mark)